# Why GenFsm is deprecated?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

Why is the `GenFsm` behavior of elixir deprecated?

I would like to implement finite state machine with `GenFsm` behavior.
I think `Agent` is not sufficient to describe finite state machine.
Because, `Agent` is not suitable for describing returning different value each state from same input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the relevant commit: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/455eb4c4ace81ce60b347558f9419fe3c33d8bf7

Basically, you can now simply use `:gen_fsm` directly from OTP, without the Elixir wrapper.

Comment: Thank you. I will use `:gen_fsm` directly.

Answer (score 5):

`:gen_fsm`  also deprecated and replaced in Erlang/OTP 20.0 by  `:gen_statem` so use Generic state machine. For more information check this link about  [Genstatem](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html)

> This is a new behavior in Erlang/OTP 19.0. It has been thoroughly
>   reviewed, is stable enough to be used by at least two heavy OTP
>   applications, and is here to stay. Depending on user feedback, we do
>   not expect but can find it necessary to make minor not backward
>   compatible changes into Erlang/OTP 20.0

Comment: Link leads to 404, please fix it up.

Answer (score 2):

The Elixir core team decided that it was too confusing and suggested that developers seek other solutions.

I wrote an Elixir wrapper around it 3 days ago, and pushed it up to hex.pm with the name gen_fsm. Here's the github page: https://github.com/pavlos/gen_fsm if you want to check it out.